# Спецификация вывода double с помощью cout

Tags: c++, double

Если `double b` равен 0.0000001 , то `cout << b` выводит 1e - 07. Как сделать так, чтобы cout выводил именно десятичную дробь целиком?

`#include <iomanip>` ... `double a = 0.0000001;` `cout << setprecision(9) << a;`

Comment: целиком - понятие растяжимое. `#include <iomanip>` `cout << setprecision (15) << b;`

Comment: @pavel Не работает, в моем коде и так уже есть `setprecision(8)`, но выводится стабильно 1e-07

Comment: тогда полностью код в вопрос как вы выводите. Попробуйте больше 8 написать.

Comment: `#include <iomanip>`
...
`double a = 0.0000001;`
`cout <<  setprecision(9) << a;`

Comment: `cout.setf(ios::fixed);` флаг выставьте. Что-то я думал что он сам выставляется.

Comment: @pavel Спасибо, после выставления флага сработало

Answer (score 6):

Нужно не только `setprecision`, но и переключиться в формат с фиксированной точкой - `fixed`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    constexpr double a=1e-9;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(18) << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/YwWwwe)