# Поведение типа double/int C++

Tags: c++, double

Заметил странное поведение типа double.

**Вопрос:**

Есть код:

```
double miles;
double km;

while(true) {

    cout << "\nEnter distance in miles: ";
    cin >> miles;

    if(miles <= 1 && miles > 0) {

        km = miles * 1.609;
        cout << "Your " << miles << " mile in kilometers: " << km << endl;

    }

    if (miles > 1) {

        km = miles * 1.609;
        cout << "Your " << miles << " miles in kilometers: " << km << endl;

    }

    if (miles == 0) {

        cout << "\nOh, no, man. Enter something but 0\n";

    }
```

Проверил все варианты if - работает, как и задумано. Но когда я вместо числа ввожу символ - выполняется последнее условие с нулем. Но это ещё не самое худшее. При этом надпись `Oh, no, man. Enter something but 0` появляется не один раз, если ввести именно 0, а она появляется постоянно (будто в бесконечном цикле). То есть цикл `while(true)` работает, но почему-то именно после ввода символа перестает запрашивать ввод у пользователя. В чем же причина?

p.s: я знаю, что while(true) - дико неправильная инструкция и их нужно избегать, просто не хотелось перезапускать программу каждый раз, чтобы проверить новое значение.

p.s.s: если ввести int вместо double, то то же самое, видимо, это не особенность именно double. Кстати, если ввести очнеь длинное число, то бесконечный цикл тоже начинается.

Comment: @pavel благодарю, исправил, понял.

Comment: По поводу урезания знаков: попробуйте вызвать `cout.precision()` с нужным количеством знаков. Только учтите, что значение `float`, нормированное к `1,...` не может быть мельче 1/2^23. В Вашем случае максимальная точность — 1/2^(23 - 4) = 1/524288 = 0,0000019073 (если ничего не путаю, т. к. 12 - это около 2^4, то есть занимает 4 бита мантиссы).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Собственно основная проблема при вводе/выводе. Выводить дробные числа следует через специальные манипуляторы ссылка на ответ:
[Спецификация вывода double с помощью cout](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/541483/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-double-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-cout?rq=1)

Если вы вводите не число (слово и.т.д.) то `cin` выставляет флаг `cin.fail` и все попытки читать из него будут заведомо неуспешными, вы можете делать сброс флага через `cin.clear();` Но нужно ещё сбросить недочитанный буфер, для этого можно сделать `cin.ignore(INT_MAX);` Но дальше уже зависит от вас.

Comment: написал `cin.clear()` в начале цикла, но, к сожалению бесконечный цикл опять повторяется.

Comment: @Muller обновил

Comment: спасибо, а есть функция, обратная к cin.clear()?